# Database listener with spring hibernate latest versions annotations

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, design-patterns

When a record is inserted/updated into a SQL Server database table(which is done by a C# application), I need to listen to the changes from the java application(Spring hibernate) and process the record.

With the new annotations and stuff is there any way we can implement a listener? 
I understand the diff between trigger and a listener. I am interested in listener here. 
Any article would be great.

I looked at hibernate interceptor which is not an option in my case.

Note C# application will be commissioned later, but for now C# app will not take any changes.

Any suggestions? please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Poll database for changes. AFAIK there is no way to have the SQL Server database send a signal to other applications that it has been updated.

Comment: Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28436018/1572269.  This will allow you to send an HTTP request to your java application via a CLR stored procedure that resides in SQL Server.

Comment: Naros and Deinum, thank you for your time and suggestions. We are going with a diff approach. All the created/updated records will be sent to a queue via a messaging service and Java application will pick it up from there.